# Django unit testing failures related to authentication settings

Tags: django, unit-testing

In Django, when I run "manage.py test", I get a lot of authentication related failures.  Some examples:

```
FAIL: test_password_change_succeeds -- AssertionError 200 != 302
FAIL: Logout without next_page option renders the default template -- AssertionError 200 != 302
```

And:

```
Failed example:
    form.non_field_errors()
Expected:
    [u'This account is inactive.']
Got:
    [u'Please enter correct username and password....']
```

I've configured settings.py so that Django will accept authentication from Apache2.  In settings, `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` includes 'AuthenticationMiddleware' and 'RemoteUserMiddleware', and `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` includes 'RemoteUserBackend'.

How do I figure out the problem here?

**UPDATE 2**
I cleared the test errors by commenting out the setting of AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS.  Now I have to think about the authentication state I need in my test environment, but at least I've cleared this issue.

The first update had a reference to a question I've since deleted.

Comment: Which version of django? There are broken tests in trunk sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above, commenting out the setting of AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS made the test errors go away.

Answer (score 0):

If your authentication only works via Apache, I wouldn't expect it to work in tests - the test runner doesn't use Apache. You will need to set up a dummy account in the normal database authentication framework.

Comment: I have such a user, created with User.objects.create_user() -- still no go.  My code is brought down from a SVN repository, and I've run ./manage.py syncdb, but is it possible that Django is expecting some state in the database that isn't present b/c I haven't gone through some step like 'django-admin.py startproject'?